# Web scraping in Javascript for site with class names that changes

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to use Puppeteer to input an address into ubereats (www.ubereats.com). I've realized that before inputting the address, I have to wait for some icon to load first or else the text just gets erased. To do for this, I'm using:

`page.waitForSelector("#wrapper > main > div.ao.ap.aq.ar.af > div.ag.bq.br.bs.bt > div > div.c1.af.bh.c2 > div > div.av.b3.ax > div > svg > path");`

Which works for now. However, the problem is that the class names occasionally change. I have not seen any noticeable pattern in the changes. I've tried using page.waitForXPath() instead because there are no class names involved, but it did not work. Is there any way to get around the changing class name? Thanks!

Edit: added some example HTML. These are innermost few divs leading up to the icon that I wait on to load. Some of these class names randomly change.

```
<div class="bi bj c3 at c4 c5 bd ae ar c6 c7 av af an">
   <div class="av b3 ax">
      <div class="c8 b1 c9">
         <svg width="24px" height="24px" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">
            <path d="M17.5834 5.16602C14.5001 2.08268 9.50008 2.08268 6.41675 5.16602C3.33341 8.24935 3.33341 13.3327 6.41675 16.416L12.0001 21.9993L17.5834 16.3327C20.6667 13.3327 20.6667 8.24935 17.5834 5.16602ZM12.0001 12.416C11.0834 12.416 10.3334 11.666 10.3334 10.7493C10.3334 9.83268 11.0834 9.08268 12.0001 9.08268C12.9167 9.08268 13.6667 9.83268 13.6667 10.7493C13.6667 11.666 12.9167 12.416 12.0001 12.416Z" fill="#000000"></path>
         </svg>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="b3 ca ah b5 b6"></div>
   <input role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" id="location-typeahead-home-input" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="location-typeahead-home-menu" aria-labelledby="location-typeahead-home-label" autocomplete="off" value="" placeholder="Enter delivery address" class="bh bd cb cc">
   <div class="b3 ca ah b5 b6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you paste some example HTML? Maybe :nth-*() selectors may help.

Comment: Added some example HTML above. I'll try using the :nth-*() selectors too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your HTML, if this icon only appears once in the page, using attribute selectors probably will work, first, search for path, child of svg, which have an attribute "d" that starts with "M17.5834 5.16602C14.5001 2.08268":

```
page.waitForSelector('svg > path[d^="M17.5834 5.16602C14.5001 2.08268"]');
```

Then, selector for the input, find input which have an attribute "placeholder" equally to "Enter delivery address":

```
input[placeholder="Enter delivery address"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors